# Android Studio 3.0 - Logcat window can not show filter input control

Tags: android, debugging, ide, android-studio-3.0

I can not type a text filter in the logcat input text control on Android Studio 3.0.1, because it is too small.

My screen is big enough. I did an event switch to fullscreen but this did not solve the problem.

See the screenshot below.

Has anyone seen this problem? How do you solve it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have similar problem but no solution found till date.

Comment: @Orbit: The problem in the screenshot of the question stems mostly from the very long device name ("Genymotion Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280"). If that is the case for you, and you are using an emulator (Genymotion, Android SDK, etc.), try to use a shorter name. Or, try the 3.1 canary version, as [this issue is supposed to be resolved there](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68299550).

Comment: lol, this is a bug, you should report it to google.

Answer (score 19):

Try clicking on the setting (cog-wheel icon) inside the logcat window and select the `windowed` or the `floating` modes, and then try to stretch the window size as long as you can

Comment: stretching to max is not necessary. In my case floated window was already sized to max width and no filter bar present. Just drag to resize to any dimension did the trick (macOs, Android Studio 3.1).

Answer (score 6):

This issue is regarding the resolution of screen size specially causing in windows platforms or desktop with small resolution.

(For windows users)

-If you have a slider toolbar set in left or right side set it to bottom.

-Check for resolution size that suits your desktop better.

-Update the windows graphic driver(Important) if you don;t see one in device manager better install it.

**Note: I had the same issues for the slider toolbar(refer 1st point) set to bottom and now it works fine.**

Answer (score 5):

use CTRL+F in logcat to find or filter logcat. then a new search bar comes below to that bar you can filter there.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Actually the problem is with the device name, which is too long and due to this it squeezes the Logcat search. So to the solution I got for this name issue is to change the device name (whether its Genymotion or AVD). So to change your device name follow below steps :

**For AVD :** Go to **Tools** --> **Android** --> **AVD Manager** --> Select your device and then change the device name to shorter one.

**For Genymotion :** Open you **VirtualBox** --> Select your device and then Click on **Settings** --> Change the name to shorter one.

And other option is Right click on **Logcat** tab and then enable **Floating mode**. Then just resize the floating window so that the Logcat search can expand.

Comment: This does not seem to work for Genymotion. When you change the name in VirtualBox, the name is not changed in Genymotion.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio 3.1-beta in the canary channel has solved this issue.

[image: Large Enough]