# How can I resize items in the LogCat window in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat

[image: Android Studio LogCat]

Hi. This has been bothering me for a long time and I haven't found any solution yet so I thought I'd ask here.

In the screenshot, you can see that the "search" part in the LogCat is really tiny because of all the other items taking up so much space. Is there a way to resize or move items around so I can see what I'm typing into search?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio 3.0 - Logcat window can not show filter input control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47645479/android-studio-3-0-logcat-window-can-not-show-filter-input-control)

Comment: if you are having this issues in windows then see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48518062/9287163

Answer (score 0):

Right click on 'Logcat' horizontal grey tab -> Select 'Floating Mode' and resize

[image]

Comment: That doesn't really help my case. I want to be able to make the Search bar bigger.

Comment: you just need a bigger screen @Bazinga